# How to calculate the coordinates of a given point inside a grid after scaling

Tags: math, geometry

If I have a 3x3 grid and scale it to 9x9 how should I calculate the new coordinates of given points going from the 3x3 to 9x9.

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnZcv.jpg) for more info

e.g.

1. Point A coordinates: (2,1) in 3x3 grid. After scaling to 9x9 the coordinate should be (5,1).
2. Point B coordinates: (2,2) in 3x3 grid. After scaling to 9x9 the coordinate should be (5,5).

Comment: x' = (x-1) ⋅ (Scale+1) + 1

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why the +1 and -1? I was thinking there would be some kind of formula to calculate those coordinates.

Comment: That it doesn't make any sense to you doesn't imply that it doesn't make any sense. How would you call what I gave you if not a _formula_? Regarding _the +1 and -1_: These stem from your coordinate origin being 1.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as we know the maximum and minimum values, max and min respectively, of our current space then this is quite nice to do.

Say we have a point with x as its x-axial value and want to scale the coordinate to be between a new range of new_max and new_min, we can use

```py
f(x)=(new_max-new_min)*((x-min)/(max-min))+new_min
```

which will return the point's x coordinate value scaled to your desired range.

Do this for all points, for both the x and y-axis and you're golden